# Extracting forest patches using square Kernels around shapefile point data in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, pixel

I have an image representing global forest cover named `minArea`. Pixels are valued 1 or 0 (tree cover or no tree cover).

I also have a shapefile imported through my assets of XY coordinate data. Coordinates in WGS84 which matches the properties of the forest map.

```
var primateocc = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/mr-beardo-5/assets/PrimateOccClean");
```

How do I extract forest patches containing an XY point within them?

In other words, I need to search for connecting pixels to the XY points using a recursive Kernel method, and retain only those pixels which are connected. This should create a new image with patches of forest around the XY points. Code below:

```
///Find connected components with the same value of the first band of the input (i.e. 0 and 1) and label them with a globally unique value

var connectedPatches = minArea.connectedComponents({
  connectedness: ee.Kernel.square(1),
  maxSize: 1024 //Creates condition for maximum size of patch. Mask areas greater than 1024 connecting pixels
});

//Calculate the tree cover area (ha). 
//Use pixelArea() to get the value of each pixel in square metres, divide by 10,000 to convert to hectare

var connectedPatchesArea = connectedPatches.select('labels').multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(10000);

///Calculate the patch area around XY data. Resolution of map is 30m

var patches = connectedPatchesArea.reduceRegions({
  collection: primateocc,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  scale: 30, 
});

Map.addLayer(connectedPatchesArea, {palette: ['green']}, 'Patches: Max size 1024');
Map.addLayer(patches, {palette: ['green']}, 'XY Patches')
```

The last part of the code is not working. In fact, `patches` just becomes a feature collection with the exact same metadata as the original shapefile. I can't figure out the code to do what I want.

Admin: please don't close this one again for not being focused enough. I cannot be anymore focused on this. All code and literature above is relevant to the problem.